# SQL WHERE SUM(value) from table where value is distinct?

Tags: sql, sum, distinct, where-clause

I know the title is strange but I don't really know to explain my problem.
I have a problem in my application and I have to change this request.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT utilisateurs.id, nom, prenom, SUM(pointages.nombre) as heuresConsommees
                        FROM utilisateurs
                        INNER JOIN pointages on pointages.cp = utilisateurs.cp                      
                        WHERE pointages.idPrestation = %d
                        AND pointages.id_affaire = %d
                        AND utilisateurs.id = %d
                        GROUP BY utilisateurs.nom,prenom, utilisateurs.id
```

My problem here is that the value pointages.nombre can be insert two times in the database, for the same affaire, prestation, and week.
I can't modify the request which allows this double insert without modifying all the architecture of my application, so I would like to know if this was possible to select the sum of the value pointages.nombre but without taking it a second time. Probably with a distinct but I don't know how to do thi in this kind of case.
Thanks by advance.

Comment: Do need to do SELECT DISTINCT since the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result!

Comment: Can there be more than one VALID entry in `pointages`? or is it always one(interms of `nombre`) entry inserted multiple times? can you show us the structure of `pointages`

Comment: There can be more than one entry in pointages,but they're not truly valid and must not appear. 
The purpose of the application is to check how many hours worked the employees. And the system allows the superior to modify the count of how many hour they worked, but when he does this, the request count them both. If the employee said he worked 5 hours and the superior say only 4, there will be 9. 

That would have been more esay to change another request from insert to update, but the application has been made around this request and if I change it, I'll have to change all the architecture.

Comment: So in fact, you only want the last entry in `pointages` per "condition"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed Group by from inner query and used an inner query to get distinct rows

Try this:-

```
SELECT id, num,prenom,SUM(nombre) as heuresConsommees
from
( 
SELECT DISTINCT utilisateurs.id, nom, prenom, pointages.nombre
                        FROM utilisateurs
                        INNER JOIN pointages on pointages.cp = utilisateurs.cp                      
                        WHERE pointages.idPrestation = %d
                        AND pointages.id_affaire = %d
                        AND utilisateurs.id = %d
) a
Group by id, num,prenom;
```

Comment: It's not working, Wampserver return this error : 

Query failed: ERREUR: column « pointages.nombre » must be in the clause GROUP BY or must be used in an agregat function.

Comment: @Lucien Serre-Fortier I have updated the query. Check it again

Comment: It's working. 
Thank you for the answer, it's perfect :)

Comment: @LucienSerre-Fortier This will not work for the example that you gave. where superior puts 4 hours whilst employee said 5 hours. you will still have 9 hours